# "Explorer.Search" cross language search criteria

Tags: vba, outlook

I noticed that the `Explorer.Search` criteria in German are different, than in English. I program an Outlook userform for many languages. Is it possible to search only in English?

Something like:

```
private sub explorer_search()
    dim objExplorer as Outlook.Explorer
    dim strFilter as String

    'a key word for choosing language or something else
    strFilter = "language:english(received:(today OR yesterday))"

    set objExplorer = Outlook.ActiveExplorer
    objExplorer.search strFilter Outlook.OlSearchScope.olSearchScopeCurrentFolder
end sub
```

I found something with a `LanguageID`. Can I set only the search language to English?

Something like:

```
objExplorer.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS     'is not working
```

I found a few sites. I think it's not possible to change the language of the explorer search, but please correct me if I am wrong.

The first page is about the [LanguageSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/DE-DE/library/office/jj230047.aspx). Each element of LanguageSettings is read-only, so I can't change anything. The element [LanguageID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/DE-DE/library/office/ff863438.aspx) is to check which language is in use in the Application. It returns the ID of the Language. For example the help language:

```
MsgBox "ID of the help language is: " & Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDHelp)
```

The other types are:

```
msoLanguageIDInstall
msoLanguageIDExeMode
msoLanguageIDUI
msoLanguageIDUIPrevious
```

Here is a link for the [MsoLanguageID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.msolanguageid.aspx) you can find there each office language.

The last link is a forum conversation about the [LanguagePreferredForEditing](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?13705-Solved-How-to-change-the-language-of-the-Spell-Checker-in-Outlook-with-a-macro) member.

The consequence being that I have a lot to translate.